# State update in React JS not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My react state seems to be one step behind. After going through answers to similar questions, it seems the solution is a useEffect hook. I've tried and haven't come up with a way to implement useEffect to solve my issue. I need values to show it's current state when I console log it. Please help

```
const [productId,setProductId] = useState("")
const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1)
const [itemName,setItemName] = useState("")
const [values, setValues] = useState({})
                                   

<Input name={item.title} id={item.id} type="number"
onChange={(e)=>{setQuantity(e.target.value)
                setItemName(e.target.name)}} />
<Button color="info" size="sm" 
onClick={ ()=>{
setSelectedItems(prevItems=>{ 
return [...prevItems, {name:itemName,quantity:quantity}] })
setValues(prevState=>{ return {...prevState, items: selectedItems } })
}}> Add </Button>

<Button
  color="info"
  onClick={()=>console.log(values)}
  disabled={!isLoading}
>Click me
</Button>
```

Link to sandbox that recreates the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-panini-8oc4g?file=/src/App.js

After selecting items and clicking 'click me' at the bottom, the items array in values is one step behind the selected items displayed on the UI. In the image below, I clearly added 3 items but clicking 'click me' shows only two in the items array.

[image]

Comment: One step behind in what? Add useEffect in your code with only a simple console.log to see what is happening to your state variable. Share your findings.

Comment: In the sandbox, the displayed selected items are not all in the items array when the 'click me' button is clicked

Comment: after clicking `Click me`, it displayes the correct data in the console. all the data, all the items amount is as showned. The issue what i find it clicking `add` not always adds the one you clicked on but that has nothing to do with `Click me` but issue in the way you add. Also, your code is all in 1 file... thats hella bad. Please be more specific of what is the issue cuz right now absed on sandbox - nothing wrong with the data that is printed into console compared to what was added/selected

Comment: Please take a look at the screenshot I just added to the question. Maybe it's only happening on my machine? Are you selecting the quantity before you add an item?

Comment: Do you have a fix for the issue with the way I add?